# Independent collections of sets whose generated $\sigma$-fields are not independent

Tags: measure-theory, independence

> Let $\Omega= \{ 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, $\mathcal{F} =$ all subsets of $\Omega$
>   , and $P(\{ i\}) = 1/4$. Give an example of two collections of sets $\mathcal{A_1}$ and $\mathcal{A_2}$ that are independent but whose generated $\sigma$-fields are not.

I took $\mathcal{A_1}=\{ \{1,2\}\}$ and $\mathcal{A_2}=\{ \{3,4\}\}$, then they are independent but note that $\sigma$ field of $\mathcal{A_1}$ contains $\{3,4\}$, then $\sigma (\mathcal{A_1})$ and $\sigma (\mathcal{A_1})$ are not independent.

But I could do this to any $\mathcal{A_1}$ and $\mathcal{A_2}$ that are subset of $\Omega$. So what is special about $P(\{ i\}) = 1/4$? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: There is nothing special with this $P$, it only makes easier to find examples. Re your $A_1$ and $A_2$ (which I assume are sets, not collections of sets, as desired), they are not independent, obviously.

Comment: sorry about that mistake @Did I edited it.

Comment: Now you have collections of sets, which are **not** independent. Can you see why?

Comment: @Did Oh! you are right, I got confused between independence and disjoint set, and disjoint set can not be independent!!

Comment: Please do not modify your question after discussions in comments about it, and answers, are posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\mathcal{A}_1=\{\{1,2\},\{1,4\}\}$ and $\mathcal{A}_2=\{\{2,4\}\}$ and note that $\{2,4\}\in\sigma(\mathcal{A}_1)$.