# Independent $\pi$-systems generate independent $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space. Two events $A,B \in \mathcal F$ are said to be *independent* of each other if $\mathbb P [A \cap B] = \mathbb P[A] \mathbb P[B]$. The collections $\mathcal A, \mathcal B \subset \mathcal F$ is said to be *independent* of each other iff $A$ is independent of $B$ for all $A \in \mathcal A$ and $B \in \mathcal B$.

It's [not necessarily true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320575/independent-collections-of-sets-whose-generated-sigma-fields-are-not-independ) that independent collections of measurable sets generate independent $\sigma$-algebras. But it seems true if the collections have more structure, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $\mathcal A, \mathcal B$ be $\pi$-system. If $\mathcal A$ is independent of $\mathcal B$, then $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ is independent of $\sigma(\mathcal B)$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** First, let's prove that $\mathcal A$ is independent of $\sigma(\mathcal B)$. Let
$$
\mathcal F_A := \{B \in \sigma(\mathcal B) : A \text{ independent of }B\} \quad \forall A \in \mathcal A.
$$

Then $\mathcal F_A$ is $\lambda$-system that contains $\mathcal B$. By $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, $\sigma(\mathcal B) \subset \mathcal F_A$ and thus $\sigma(\mathcal B) = \mathcal F_A$ for all $A \in \mathcal A$. This implies $\{A\}$ is independent of $\sigma(B)$ for all $A \in \mathcal A$.

Second, let's prove that $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ is independent of $\sigma(\mathcal B)$. Let
$$
\mathcal F := \{A \in \sigma(\mathcal A) : \{A\} \text{ independent of } \sigma(\mathcal B)\}.
$$

Then  $\mathcal F$ is $\lambda$-system that contains $\mathcal A$. By $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, $\sigma(\mathcal A) \subset \mathcal F$ and thus $\sigma(\mathcal A) = \mathcal F$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Your proof seems right. You may know this already: if $\{\mathcal{C_t}: t \in T\}$ is a collection of independent $\pi$-systems, then $\{\sigma(\mathcal{C}_t):t\in T\}$ is a collection of independent $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you so much for your verification! Actually, I was trying to prove a special case of your statement ($T = \{1, 2\}$).

Comment: @OliverDíaz Could you help me with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617556/how-is-u-measurable-in-this-construction-involved-taylors-expansion) question?

Comment: I wrote a posting on your question a few minutes ago.