# If $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is independent, then $\mathcal F_n$ is independent of $\mathcal G_{n+1}$

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$. For $n \in \mathbb N$, let
$$
\mathcal F_n := \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)
\quad \text{and} \quad
\mathcal G_{n+1} := \sigma(X_{n+1}, X_{n+2}, \ldots).
$$

In proving Kolmogorov's zero–one law, my lecture note uses the following result

> **Theorem** If $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is independent, then $\mathcal F_n$ is independent of $\mathcal G_{n+1}$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** Let $\mathcal A := \sigma(X_1) \cup \cdots \cup \sigma(X_n)$ and $\mathcal B := \sigma(X_{n+1})  \cup \sigma(X_{n+2}) \cup \cdots$. By definition, $\mathcal F_n := \sigma(\mathcal A)$ and $\mathcal G_{n+1} := \sigma (\mathcal B)$. Let $\lambda(\mathcal A)$ be the smallest $\lambda$-system that contains $\mathcal A$. We define $\lambda(\mathcal B)$ similarly.

Let's prove that $\lambda(\mathcal A)$ is independent of $\lambda(\mathcal B)$. Fix $A \in \lambda(\mathcal A)$ and $B \in \lambda(\mathcal B)$. Then there are $A_i \in \sigma(X_i)$ for $i=1, \ldots, n$ such that $A=\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i$. There is $N \in \mathbb N$ and $A_i \in \sigma(X_i)$ for $i=n+1, \ldots, N$ such that $B=\bigcap_{i=n+1}^N A_i$. Because $(X_n)$ is independent,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P[A \cap B] &= \mathbb P \left [ \bigcap_{i=1}^N A_i \right ] \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^N \mathbb P[A_i] \\
&= \left (\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb P[A_i] \right ) \left (\prod_{i=n+1}^N \mathbb P[A_i] \right ) \\
&= \mathbb P \left [ \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \right ] \mathbb P \left [ \bigcap_{i=n+1}^N A_i \right ] \\
&= \mathbb P[A] \mathbb P[B].
\end{align}
$$

Finally, independent $\pi$-systems [generate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617494/independent-pi-systems-generate-independent-sigma-algebras) independent $\sigma$-algebras. This completes the proof.